# Does an instant app support Bluetooth

Tags: android-instant-apps

I have to change existing app to an instant app.

While editing, there was a problem with bluetooth permission.

Does an instant app support Bluetooth?

Comment: Hi Juhun and welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried so far to answer this question?  Have you read any of the Instant App documentation, or researched similar questions?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth is not yet supported by Instant Apps. Check the Instant App FAQS permissions and you will notice these are the supported features as of now:

> - BILLING
> - ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
> - ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
> - ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
> - CAMERA
> - INSTANT_APP_FOREGROUND_SERVICE only in Android 8.0.
> - INTERNET
> - READ_PHONE_NUMBERS. This permission is available only in Android 8.0 (API level 26).
> - RECORD_AUDIO
> - VIBRATE

Comment: Here is the FAQ doc with those permissions listed: https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/faqs