# Is it possible to make an Android Instant app with bluetooth through web api

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, webapi, android-instant-apps

iOS App Clips [supports Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650310), but Android Instant apps [do not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490458/does-an-instant-app-support-bluetooth).

Is it possible to make an Android Instant app with a web view that uses the Bluetooth [web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API)?

This is more a theoretical question and out of curiosity than if it is a good idea. So stability and UX should not be taken into consideration.